# Android 4 Fragment Action Bar Not Showing

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-4.4-kitkat

I use Linear Layout inside a Relative Layout. Because of this, the action bar is not showing up. It works fine both on Android 5 and 6. This problem only occurs in Android 4.  Could you please help me?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.blabla">
<LinearLayout
    android:paddingTop="60dp"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/act_left"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@color/background_gray_soft">
....
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: don't use actionbar, use toolbar dude, and when U ask question provide more useful code so that we can help you.

Comment: I opened up a Navigation Drawer project. Have not changed any code except an activity's xml. I only added a linear layout inside a relative layout. It works on Android 5 and 6 as I said above. However, in Android 4 it does not show the Action bar as well as the hamburger icon. Now, is this info enough for you bro? @ErfanMowlaei

Comment: nope it is not, I can not help you with this snippet and explanation really. you can call me whatever you want but to me your info is incomplete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who uses FrameLayouts with Fragments in ICS, do not change your background with

```
android:backgound="..."
```

It makes the Toolbar color same with your background.(I have no idea why. Still trying to figure it out.)

You need to check your API version in your Java code and set the background color there.

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.fragment_container);
            frameLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.background_gray_soft));
        }
```

There is only one problem left and that could not be solved with this method.

If you want to have a special background color in ICS(I only encountered this problem with Fragments), how will you set that?